# Ship, is not shooting

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

The ship is not shooting, even if I press space. This is truly frustrating and the aliens are note generating either, can someone help? The code is below.

alien.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Alien(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Alien, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True
        
    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor *
                        self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

alien_invasioin.py:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
import random
from pygame.sprite import Group
from alien import Alien
class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, size1, size2, colour):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([size1, size2])
        self.image.fill(colour)


        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y

allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(1, 250):
    num = random.randint(1,3)
    stars = Square(random.randint(0, 1000), random.randint(0, 700), num, num, (255, 255, 255))
    allspriteslist.add(stars)

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("PEWPEWPEWPOWPOW DIE YOU LITTLE ALIEN ____S ")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
    
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
        gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
        allspriteslist.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        

run_game()
```

bullet.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
            ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor
    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y
    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

game_functions.py:

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import  Alien
def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit
        
def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour)
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    aliens.draw(screen)

def update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    bullets.update()
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
            
    check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

def check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)    
    if len(aliens) == 0:
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)

def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
            break
        
def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
    ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1
    
def update_aliens(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height -
                            (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height,
        alien.rect.height)
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        #screen stuff
        self.screen_width = 1000
        self.screen_height = 750
        self.bg_colour = (0, 0, 0)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 0, 255, 0
        self.bullets_allowed = 7
        self.alien_speed_factor = 1
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        self.fleet_direction = 1
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

This is kind of frustrating, so please help.
Anyways, it seems like my post is mostly made out of code, and need more details, I'm sorry about that!

Comment: way way way too much code. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `"it seems like my post is mostly made out of code, and need more details, so I'm gonna write this here."` How about actually providing more details instead of dummy text to pass the validation?

Comment: What debugging have you tried? If you do not have a debugger/IDE, have you tried adding print statements into the code to track if it is reaching where you expect it should when you hit space or when the aliens are supposed to generate? Print statements show up in the black window, not the game window.

Comment: This is not a problem, since I believe it is still a correct form for `super()`, but for some reason in the `Bullet` and `Alien` class you have used this form of the super call  `super(Bullet, self).__init__()` and `super(Alien, self).__init__()` respectively, instead of the usual `super().__init__()` form that you do use in the `Square` class. I don't think it is actually wrong, it is just unnecessary and makes you have to hard code the class name into it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `aliens.add(alien)` at the end of `create_fleet`:

```py
def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    # [...]

    aliens.add(alien)
```

Explanation:

The bullets are constructed correctly, but the are destroyed immediately in `check_bullet_alien_collisions`:

> ```py
> def check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
>    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)    
>    if len(aliens) == 0:
>        bullets.empty()
>        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
> ```

The bullets are destroyed by `bullets.empty()`, because the the group `aliens` is empty. The group is empty, because you missed to append the 1st alien to the group when it is constructed in `create_fleet`:

```py
def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, alien.rect.height)
    
    aliens.add(alien) # <-- this is missing in your code
```

Comment: I think that your diagnosis is correct, but not the resolution..`create_fleet()` is likely intended to create a fleet not just one alien.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh It is the shortest solution. Anyway, I think the contributor follows a tutorial and missed that on line.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Rabbid76 was very close on this but did not get it quite right this time (unusual for him/her). The diagnosis was correct, but not the resolution. It is in here:

```py
def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height,
        alien.rect.height)
```

But `create_fleet()` is likely intended to create a fleet not just one alien. So I expect this is the needed behavior:

```py
def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    #alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)  <--- remove this!!!
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height,
        alien.rect.height)

    for col_number in number_aliens_x:
        for row_number in number_rows:
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, col_number, row_number)
```

I actually missed the problem when I first looked at this. Just now after seeing Rabbid76's answer I realized that he/she found the problem, but do not think that she/he provided the proper resolution (based on the name of the method `create_fleet` and the fact that it was looking up the number of rows and columns but then not using them).